# Extract Multiple Occurances of Variable Length Text Without Multiple Patterns

Tags: c#, .net, regex

From the following data `.xxx[val1, val2, val3]` the values of `val1`, `val2` and `val3` need to be extracted.

If one uses this pattern `@"\[(.*?), (.*?), (.*?)\]"` the data can be extracted, but when the data string varies it fails to get *all* data.

Take these variable examples

`.xxx[val1]` 
or `.xxx[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]`
or finally `.xxx[{1-N},]`.

What *single* regular expression pattern can achieve results on all sets of data provided as examples?

Comment: If you can't define the patterns then you'll be hard pressed to create a suitable regex to match them. A lot of ground is covered by "the string can vary."

Comment: Ausgezeichnet question actually. I have reworded it for an English speaking audience, but it was clear to myself what you were asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would be the correct pattern for this?

The best practice is not to match the unknown, but design your pattern after the knowns. In similar practice, not blindly match using the `.*` (zero or more of anything) for backtracking can be horrendously slow; why add to complexity when it is not needed.

Frankly one should favor the `+` one or more usage more than `*` zero or more which should really be used when specific items may not appear.

> the string can vary.

It appears by your example that if we were to think like a compiler, the tokens are separated by either a `,` or an ending `]`. So let us develop a pattern with that knowledge (the knowns).

The best way to capture is to consume until a known is found. Using the *not* set of `[^ ]` pattern is best; which says match a character **not** in this set. Then add our total quantifier the `+` which says one or more. Effectively replacing the `.*` in your old pattern but in *reverse*.

---

```
var data = ".xxx[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]";

var pattern = @"
[^[]+                     # Consume anything that is *not* a brace
                          #  but don't match it , (.xxx is the first anchor)
\[                        # Starting brace consumed
(                       # Start of match captures
   (?<Token>[^\s,\]]+)    # Named Match grouping called `Token` where one or more
                          # of anything not a space, comma or end brace is captured.
   [\s,\]]+               # Consume the token's `,` or space or final bracket.
)+                      # End match captures, one or more
]                         # Ending brace."
;

// IgnorePatternWhitespace allows us to comment the pattern, 
// does not affect parser processing.

Regex.Match(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .Groups["Token"]
     .Captures
     .OfType<Capture>()
     .Select(cp => cp.Value);
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could capture `@"\[(.*?)\]"` in a first step and then split on the `,` which would certainly be a lot faster than using a regexp to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

An easier  way to do this just match everything inside `[]` and then split the match.

```
text.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1].split(", "); //And now you have an array with var1,var2..etc
```

Here's a javascript example, I don't do c#, so don't want to mess it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite a Group overwrites it's value if its repeated, it stores the whole stack of captures as a Capture Collection, returned by each group in Group.Captures Property.

> **[Group.Captures Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx)**
>
> The real utility of the Captures property occurs when a quantifier is applied to a capturing group so that the group captures multiple substrings in a single regular expression. In this case, the Group object contains information about the last captured substring, whereas the Captures property contains information about all the substrings captured by the group.

Then, you can simply use this pattern:

```
\[(?:([^,\]]+),?\s*)+\]
```

**Code:**

```
string pattern = @"\[(?:([^,\]]+),?\s*)+\]";
var re = new Regex( pattern);
var text = @".xxx[val1, val2, val3]";


MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(text);
for (int mnum = 0; mnum < matches.Count; mnum++)
{   //loop matches
    Match match = matches[mnum];
    Console.WriteLine("Match #{0} - Value: {1}", mnum + 1, match.Value);
    int captureCtr = 0;
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures)
    {  //loop captures for the 1st Group
       Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}", 
                         captureCtr, capture.Value);
       captureCtr += 1;                  
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Match #1 - Value: [val1, val2, val3]
      Capture 0: val1
      Capture 1: val2
      Capture 2: val3
```

- [ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/MyK41G)